# Can't find element selenium even though it certainly exists

Tags: python, selenium

I have some trouble finding a element here [Link](https://sports.williamhill.com/betting/en-gb/football/competitions/OB_TY295/English-Premier-League/matches/OB_MGMB/Match-Betting)

I want to scrape the names of the matches using:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[7]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/main/div[2]/div/div/div/div//div/div/div/article/main/a/span')))
```

(I don't like using the XPath, but otherwise I'd also get the bets that weren't just full time result bets)

But when I run this it returns an empty list.
I have tried figuring out wether the match names are within an iframe or something but I can't figure it out. Does someone know how I can scrape these elements?

N.B. I have checked multiple times whether the XPath is actually in the HTML and it is.

Answer (score 1):

so the code you are using is to wait the page to load until the xpath is found. I wrote the code below and it works. It just prints dates too, you need to adjust. However I just run it so I am confident it works. Ensure you load all the dependencies in the top. It works with class and not xpath.

```
driver.get("https://sports.williamhill.com/betting/en-gb/football/competitions/OB_TY295/English-Premier-League/matches/OB_MGMB/Match-Betting")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    lambda x: x.find_element_by_class_name('sp-o-market__title').is_displayed())
out = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sp-o-market__title')
for item in out:
    item = item.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    item = item.split('<span>')[1]
    item = item.split("</span>")[0]
    print(item)
```

Produces:

```
Arsenal v Norwich
Brentford v Brighton
```

Comment: Your solution works fine indeed and I got rid of the dates quite easily. Could you elaborate on the part within the for loop? I would like to do the same with the odds but I don't quite understand how your solution works. So I am not able to reproduce/adjust it accordingly.

Comment: Sure, so you notice the `find_elements_by_class_name` notice the s in elements. So you can loop over them. Then you need the html that's inside. After you need just the text within the `<span>` and voila. Please add `print(item)` after each line inside the loop that will help you understand what item is going through.

Comment: `split` is a method you can split in array pieces a string (takes as input the delimiter point or no input). Have some reading on these methods also get_attribute and happy to help you again! Happy coding.